# Somar coluna de tempo no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho uma coluna do tipo **time** em uma tabela. Com registros como:

```
00:02:15
00:09:47
00:00:25
...
```

Preciso, no meu *select*, buscar a soma desses minutos em formato **time**. Exemplo de retorno: `00:12:27`

Tentei de diversas formas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 7):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
create table t1 (id int, t time)

insert into t1 values (1,'00:00:25.0000000')
insert into t1 values (1,'00:12:20.0000000')

insert into t1 values (2,'00:00:02.0000000')
insert into t1 values (2,'00:00:10.0000000')

SELECT ID, CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECOND,SUM(DATEDIFF
(MILLISECOND,0,CAST(T AS DATETIME))),0) AS TIME) FROM t1
GROUP BY ID
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b2c3c/2)

Comment: Devo dizer que fiquei confuso entre os `casts`, `dateadd` e `sum`

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar uma combinação de [DATEADD](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) e [DATEDIFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) para calcular a diferença do intervalo em horas, e [CAST](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) ao final para converter para o format `TIME` assim:

```
select CAST(DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', hora)), '00:00:00.000') as time)
```

Exemplo:

```
declare @t table (hora time)
insert into @t values ('00:02:15')
insert into @t values ('00:09:47')

select CAST(DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', hora)), '00:00:00.000') as time) from @t
```

Note que o segredo é somar a diferença entre a hora '00:00:00' e a hora do campo do banco.

Baseado nessa reposta do SO em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535718/sum-total-time-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

O jeito mais simples de fazer o que deseja é:

```
SELECT 
    ID, CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD (ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, 0, T)), 0)) AS TIME 
FROM 
    T1
GROUP BY 
    ID
```